# Prepopulate/Precheck check boxes based on Mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I have a form with 3 checkboxes in html: Chicago, SF, NYC.

A user can check off any of those checkboxes. The data then gets sent to my database, and I implode the data such that it is stored as individual values rather than an array.

```
$locationpref = implode(", ",$_POST['locationpref']);
```

When I refresh my page, I would like for my form to precheck the checkboxes that the user has already selected. For example, if I select Chicago and SF as my preferences, anytime I log in to my profile I would like to see those boxes checked off.

I understand the html behind it, but since the implode converts the array to a string, I cannot figure out how to search the string for "SF" or "Chicago" and then trigger the echo function accordingly.

```
<?php if (in_array("SF", $locationpref)) {echo "checked='checked'";} ?>
```

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/explode

Comment: First you need to explode the location data with coma.

Comment: I should have clarified: I have exploded the locations with coma, but when I search with in_array function, for some reason it only detects the first item of the array. For example, it will only detect 'Chicago' in the exploded array, but not SF or NYC. Do you happen to know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
U need to explode the locations with coma.

$locations = "Chicago,SF,NYC";
$locationpref = explode(','$locations);
```

then use

```
if (in_array("SF", $locationpref)) {echo "checked='checked'";}
```

Comment: I should have clarified: I have exploded the locations with coma, but when I search with in_array function, for some reason it only detects the first item of the array. For example, it will only detect 'Chicago' in the exploded array, but not SF or NYC. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: don't add space while exploding or imploding after come

Answer (score 0):

You've obviously discovered `implode()` but not its opposite, `explode()`, for converting in the other direction.

```
if (in_array("SF", explode(',', $locationpref))) echo "checked='checked'";
```

Or you could just REGEX, looking for the words encased in word boundaries:

```
if (preg_match('/\bSF\b/', $locationpref)) echo "checked='checked'";
```